# Python Requests to Forge API - 401 Response "Authorization failed"

Tags: python-3.x, autodesk-forge

```
def get_token():
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    data = {'client_id': 'XXX', 'client_secret': 'XXX', 'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': 'data:read'}
    response = requests.post('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate', headers=headers, data=data)
    return response.json()['access_token']

print('Bearer ' + get_token())
response_form_templates = requests.get('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/forms/v1/projects/:projectId/form-templates', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + get_token()})
print(response_form_templates.json())
print(response_form_templates)
```

I'm trying to use python requests to simply get back the form-templates and all I'm getting back is a 401 response and a message saying "Authorization failed". The few print statements in there are from my trying to debug what's going wrong, but with my client_id and client_secret in there, it gives me those errors.

Any idea as to what could be wrong would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: I see you print a bearer token. Does the server where you post use bearer authorization token? If yes, you need to include the authorization token in the headers **headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': f'Bearer {get_token()}'}**

Comment: @AlexandruPlacinta It does, the server sends back a bearer token. The authorization token is included in the headers of the get request. That just updated, let me give that a shot.

Comment: My bad. I did not see. Do you get a cookie too?

Comment: @AlexandruPlacinta No cookie is sent, the Forge API docs just say you need to set the scope to data:read for the endpoint I'm hitting and then pass in the access_token.

Comment: You have projects/:projectId. Don't you need to set the **:projectId**?

Comment: @AlexandruPlacinta You're definitely right, the docs example confused me. That's most likely the problem

Answer (score 1):

Btw. we don't have an official Forge SDK for Python yet but there's a simple, unofficial one here: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-sdk-python that you could perhaps use as a reference when building the HTTP requests yourself. For example, here's how the SDK retrieves the 2-legged access token: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-sdk-python/blob/develop/src/autodesk_forge_sdk/auth.py#L147-L178.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **2-legged token** instead of a **3-legged token**. As you can see from the image below, you **require a 3-legged token** when you want to [retrieve form templates](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/forms/#step-1-find-the-form-template-ids).

[image]

Use this [link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v1/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) and see how you can get a 3-legged token.